# wierd/whacky blender animations

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

[image]OKay, it's taken me I think about 12 hours of getting really upset until I finally "kind" of figured something out. Wondering if someone can give me an insight as to why this is happening, and an easier workaround.

If I have a file that I've done transformations on (i.e., simple subdivision modifier, then animating a collision between two bodies) - and I skip around from frame to frame to preview... If I try 'rendering' a random frame - it is 100% 'whacky' (like the object will be totally distorted, etc). It's like it needs to start from frame 0, and manually calculate all the way up to say frame 300 to figure out what it 'should' look like.

But if I "manually" step through the ENTIRE project, from frame 0, to 1, to 2, etc, etc, etc... then frame 300 will look proper.

a) Is there a way of baking ALL the physics, etc prior to tranformation? I couldn't seem to find anything like that (other than 'some' physics allow baking, i.e., smoke simulations in domains). The collission/soft body doesn't seem to have any bake, at least that I could find.

b) Anything else I need to know so I render files properly without glitches?

Thanks very much!